# Can the voice be trained to sound tremulous when singing?

Tags: voice, blues

I was inspired to ask this after I've listened to some KALEO, whose lead singer's voice has an interesting tremor that compliments the blues-inspired style.

I'd like to give this live performance as an example (I recommend listening to the whole performance for enjoyment):

with the following timestamps:

- 2:57-3:15 (3:10 more powerful and highlighted)
- 4:09
- 4:15

I'm sorry if it's a very basic technique. I just want to know how's it called, if it's achievable(or just something you're born with), or a throat disease (like the google results say).

Thank you for your time!

Another performance that highlights the style mentioned:

Comment: Trying to catch his tremolo, but can't.

Answer (score 2):

**Tremolo and vibrato**

Tremolo deals with change in volume, whereas vibrato deals with change in pitch. For vibrato you have to tense a muscle around the vocal chords periodically, that is easy.

**Change in volume: airflow or coarticulation**

For a change in volume, maintaining the same vowel, you'd need to vary the airflow through the vocal chords periodically. When you manipulate volume using the mouth, you will get another vowel, which is not appropriate for most songs. I would say it has to be air volume.

**..to train them**

Stop smoking

For tremolo, e.g. how fast can you say A-A-A-A-A

For vibrato, refer to the video posted in Brian Towers' answer

Making howling, crying or laughing sounds can invoke both tremolo and vibrato.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know how's it called

It is called "vibrato". It is a variation in pitch and, usually also, volume, which, as you note, makes the singing sound more interesting.

> if it's achievable

Yes. Most (All?) classically trained singers use vibrato. There are YouTube videos out there which describe the exercises you can do to develop vibrato. Here is one example which explains what vibrato is and then gives exercise which help you develop the variations in first volume then pitch:

Comment: I was referring to that crispy almost chocked slide happening at 4:09 when he sings the 2nd part of the word 'shame', or at 4:15 where he sings 'crossed MY MIND'.

Comment: There's an awful lot of (a lot of awful?) opera singers who use so much vibrato it's difficult to decide what the actual note is they're supposed to be singing. Tremolo works better, but I'm convinced there's another sort, which changes tone, somehow.

Comment: Tremolo deals with change in volume, whereas vibrato deals with change in pitch. For vibrato you have to tense a muscle around the vocal chords periodically, that is easy. For a change in volume, you'd somehow have to vary the airflow through the vocal chords. No idea if that is trained with the same techniques, but there's really a difference. Crying and laughing can involve tremolo *and* vibrato.